# How to get stage in controller

Tags: javafx, controller, stage

I am having controller and working FXML file but I want to maximize my window onLoad. So I want stage refrence in my java controller class.

Without stage I am not able to maximize my window right?

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you explain the context? You are loading one FXML file inside the `initialize()` method for a controller for another FXML file? Where is `myStage` initialized in the "current" controller?

Comment: private Stage myStage; -- Initialize

public void setStage(Stage stage) {
      this.myStage = stage;
 }

Comment: I found that every start method is having the stage. but in my case there is no start method.

Comment: The `start()` method is defined in the `Application` subclass, not in the controllers. Can't you just maximize it there?

Comment: I am having start() method but it will invoke one launchbar and that launchbar having 4-5 applications and my application is one of them.

Comment: OK, but somewhere you are loading the FXML to which the controller is connected. And then you are doing something with the loaded root of the FXML. At that point in the code you should be able to get a reference to the `Stage` and maximize it. Otherwise just maximize it when it is passed to `setStage(...)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX Class controller Stage/Window reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015537/javafx-class-controller-stage-window-reference)

Comment: @Uluk Biy - that is giving me null pointer exception.

My code : 

                `code` String resource = "ClsMain.fxml";

  URL location1 = getClass().getResource(resource);
  FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
  fxmlLoader.setLocation(location1);
  fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());

  ClsMainController controller = (ClsMainController) fxmlLoader.getController();

  Stage dialogStage = new Stage();

  controller.setStage(dialogStage);
  
  this.myStage.setMaximized(true); `code`

Comment: @user3910235 you should do fxmlLoader.load(); before the fxmlLoader.getController();